# How to push the data into database using javafx

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I am editing the question that i added yesterday because i solved that issue. Now i want to know that, is there any specific way to push the data into database?

I am using sqlite database ( firefox plugin ) and eclipse for coding.

Thank you

Comment: Can you update your question with the stack trace?

Comment: you need to point out the lines which throw exception. We can't tell which line is 45 and which one is 37

Comment: what is stack trace?

Comment: question edited

Comment: @siddharthpal Please add the line `e.printStackTrace()` to the `catch` block, and post the [stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450) in your question.

Comment: stack trace updates

Comment: Well, that null pointer exception is apparently in your catch block. As I asked before, print the stack trace of the exception that is thrown that gets you to the catch block in the first place, and post *that* stack trace.